# Question about the maximum of a function of two integrals

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Consider a sufficiently regular bivariate function $J(x,y)$. I would like to maximize
$$ J\left(\int_0^T f(t) g(t) \mathrm{d} t, \int_0^T f(t)^2 h(t) \mathrm{d} t \right) $$
in $f$.

If I replace $f(t)$ with $f(t) +\varepsilon \eta(t)$ and take $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\epsilon} \big|_{\varepsilon=0}$, I get the first order condition:
$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial x} \int_0^T g(t) \eta(t) \mathrm{d} t + 
\frac{\partial J}{\partial y} \int_0^T 2 f(t) h(t) \eta(t) \mathrm{d} t = 0.$$

Is it okay to then move $\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial J}{\partial y}$ inside the integrals to get
$$ f_*(t) \propto \frac{g(t)}{h(t)}?$$

Finding the proportionality constant might be intractable, but it's quite useful to have the shape of the solution.